# [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Array

I'm trying to take lines from a file and separate them at a `:` and put them into another file as two separate lines then run it through an app and separate the lines by whether they work or not.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const conf = '.\\login.conf'
const directory = '.\\input\\'
fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(files => {
        var files_directory = directory + files
        fs.readFile(files_directory, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {console.log('error', err)}
            var data_array = data.split(' ')
            var spaced_data_array = data_array + ' '
            Array.from(spaced_data_array)
            var d = spaced_data_array.split(' ')
            console.log(d)
            var data = d + ''
                login = data.split(':')
                fs.writeFile(conf, login, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {console.log('error', err)}
                })
                require('child_process').exec('.\\ovpnconnector.exe start nordvpn.ovpn')
                if (work = 0) {
                    console.log('Not Working')
                    fs.writeFile('.\\output\\not_working.txt', holder, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {console.log('error', err)}
                    })
                }
                if (work = 1) {
                    console.log('Working')
                    fs.writeFile('.\\output\\working.txt', holder, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {console.log('error', err)}
                    })
                }
         })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block causes the error:

```
  login = data.split(':')
                fs.writeFile(conf, login, (err, result) => {
```

`login` is an array and it cannot be used as the second parameter of the `fs.writeFile` method. You can see it in the error message:

```
The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Array
```

#### Action

What you're trying to do:

> take lines from a file and separate them at a : and put them into
> another file as two separate lines

You can merge the array to string by the newline character.

```
  login = data.split(':').join('\r\n')
                fs.writeFile(conf, login, (err, result) => {
```